# How to preselect a default object using Ember.select

Tags: ember.js

and I'm currently using Ember.select for a drop down menu, and while there's a default value showing, the object does't appear to actually be selected. When IO render the page, the modal open up but the value for selected_funding_instrument is undefined until I click on the drop down menu. Any tips?

debit-customer-modal.hbs:

```
  <div {{bindAttr class=":control-group model.validationErrors.source_uri:error"}}>
            <label class="control-label">Account number</label>
            <div class="controls">
                {{view Ember.Select
                    contentBinding="customer.debitable_funding_instruments"
                    valueBinding="model.source_uri"
                    optionValuePath="content.uri"
                    optionLabelPath="content.description_with_type"
                    class="span8"
                }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Account holder's name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <span class="label1a">{{selected_funding_instrument.name}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

debit_customer_modal.js

```
require('app/components/modal');

Balanced.DebitCustomerModalComponent = Balanced.ModalComponent.extend({
submitAction: 'submitDebitCustomer',

dollar_amount: null,

actions: {
    open: function() {
        var fundingInstruments = this.get('customer.debitable_funding_instruments');
        var debitUri = (fundingInstruments && fundingInstruments.length > 0) ? fundingInstruments[0].get('debits_uri') : null;

        var debit = Balanced.Debit.create({
            uri: debitUri,
            amount: null,
            order: this.get('order.href')
        });

        this.set('dollar_amount', null);
        var selfie = this.get('selected_funding_instrument');
        this._super(debit);
    },

    save: function() {
        if (this.get('model.isSaving')) {
            return;
        }

        var debit = this.get('model');
        var selfie = this.get('selected_funding_instrument');
        if (selfie) {
            debit.set('uri', selfie.get('debits_uri'));
        }

        var cents = null;
        try {
            cents = Balanced.Utils.dollarsToCents(this.get('dollar_amount'));
        } catch (error) {
            debit.set('validationErrors', {
                'amount': error
            });
            return;
        }
        debit.set('amount', cents);
        this._super(debit);
    }
},

selected_funding_instrument: function() {
    var sourceUri = this.get('model.source_uri');
    if (sourceUri) {
        return this.get('customer.debitable_funding_instruments').find(function(fundingInstrument) {
            return sourceUri === fundingInstrument.get('uri');
        });
    }
}.property('model.source_uri', 'customer.debitable_funding_instruments'),


can_debit: function() {
    return this.get('customer.debitable_funding_instruments.length') > 0;
}.property('customer.debitable_funding_instruments')
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You need to fire up `selected_funding_instrument`

```
Balanced.DebitCustomerModalComponent = Balanced.ModalComponent.extend({
    init: function () {
        this.selected_funding_instrument();

        return this._super();
    }
}):
```

It would be nice if you can create fiddle.

Comment: The initialization now throws me the following Type Error: TypeError: Property 'selected_funding_instrument' of object [object Object] is not a function    Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XGAM9/1/

Comment: @rserna2010 your fiddle doesn't work because you are using Handlebars syntax in HTML file. BTW, http://jsbin.com seems to be better because there is console so we can see actually errors.